# c# Selenium, select specific Firefox Profile

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am trying to get my selenium to use Firefox with a specific profile (To keep cookies and such in the browser).

However, all the code i am finding for this is outdated, and i cant seem to find a way to use this via the latest selenium and geckodriver.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Allright, i got it to work and am answering my own questions for others that have the same issue.

Step 1: Create a new profile using the profile manager
Step 2: Set the profile directory to something custom (To make it easier)

Code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"D:\FFprofile");
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.Profile = profile;

            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Then FF opens with this profile